# INVALID_TYPE when creating salesforce attachment

Tags: php, soap, salesforce, nusoap

Bellow is the XML POST and Response i get from the sales force servers.
Im trying to add an attachment to an Account but i keep getting INVALID_TYPE.

Im using NuSoap instead of the SalesForce PHP library because the server i'm working on doesnt have the SOAP extension required.

I have no issue with going in and amending the library to make it work but i dont have a clue whats wrong with the XML to fix the issue. I get query information perfectly fine.

All help and advice appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <nu2113:SessionHeader xmlns:nu2113="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
        <sessionId>00Di00000{---cutting out for privacy--}UrYmByvpO5yRWIK0Gmy</sessionId>
    </nu2113:SessionHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <create xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
        <sObject>
            <type xsi:type="xsd:string">Attachment</type>
            <fieldsToNull>
                <elementName xsi:type="xsd:string">fieldsToNull</elementName>
                <values xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[5]">
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">OwnerId</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">IsPrivate</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">IsPartnerShared</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">ConnectionSentId</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">BodyLength</item>
                </values>
            </fieldsToNull>
            <Id xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ParentId xsi:type="xsd:string">001i000000JG17b</ParentId>
            <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Test document</Name>
            <Description xsi:type="xsd:string">Test upload from WIN form</Description>
            <ContentType xsi:type="xsd:string">.pdf</ContentType>
            <Body xsi:type="xsd:string">hello</Body>
        </sObject>
    </create>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>


HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Date: Mon, 13 Jan 2014 15:49:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 676

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode>sf:INVALID_TYPE</faultcode>
        <faultstring>INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type.</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <sf:InvalidSObjectFault xsi:type="sf:InvalidSObjectFault">
                <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_TYPE</sf:exceptionCode>
                <sf:exceptionMessage>Must send a concrete entity type.</sf:exceptionMessage>
                <sf:row>-1</sf:row>
                <sf:column>-1</sf:column>
            </sf:InvalidSObjectFault>
        </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line might be the problem:

```
<ContentType xsi:type="xsd:string">.pdf</ContentType>
```

that is not a valid content type. try this:

```
<ContentType xsi:type="xsd:string">application/pdf</ContentType>
```

Comment: Sadly that did nothing.

Comment: Same error? have you put base64encoded string of the pdf file you are uploading into `<Body xsi:type="xsd:string"></Body>`?

Comment: Yes. I did. But i just replaced it with dummy text because displaying a 1MB PDF in b64 each time i refreshed was impractical.

Do you know what i can see an example of a "create" request in XML. All of the docs just show Java/C# code. Not the XML its self.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Soap, so I don't use it, hence can't answer. Have a look at their CURL api usage guide: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/api_rest.pdf‎ - it appears to be well documented and quite easy as you can use curl in php.

Comment: The issue with that is inserting BLOBs isnt 100% implement by the API. It needs to be manually enabled. (I would rather have used it but was told no.). So im stuck with SOAP and its horrors.